# What exactly is happening in this piece of code?

Tags: python, debugging

I attempted to recreate a piece of code which is basically a minimalist Tomagatchi like thing. However when it is fed, and listened to, it's "mood" value does not change. It remains "mad". Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
{#Create name, hunger, boredom attributes. Hunger and Boredom are numberical attributes

class Critter(object):
    def __init__(self, name, hunger = 0, boredom = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.hunger = hunger
        self.boredom = boredom

    #Creating a private attribute that can only be accessed by other methods
    def __pass_time(self):
        self.hunger += 1
        self.boredom += 1

    def __get_mood(self):
        unhappiness = self.hunger + self.boredom
        if unhappiness < 5:
            mood = "happy"
        if 5 <= unhappiness <= 10:
            mood = "okay"
        if 11 <= unhappiness <= 15:
            mood = "frustrated"
        else:
            mood = "mad"
        return mood

    mood = property (__get_mood)

    def talk(self):
        print "Hi! I'm",self.name,"and I feel",self.mood,"now."
        self.__pass_time()

    def eat(self, food = 4):
        print "Brrruuup. Thank you!"
        self.hunger -= food
        if self.hunger < 0:
            self.hunger = 0
        self.__pass_time()

    def play(self, play = 4):
        print "Yaaay!"
        self.boredom -= play
        if self.boredom < 0:
            self.boredom = 0
        self.__pass_time()

    def main ():
        crit_name = raw_input("What do you want to name your critter? ")
        crit = Critter (crit_name)

    choice = None
    while choice != "0":
        print \
              """  0 - Quit
                   1 - Listen to your critter.
                   2 - Feed your critter
                   3 - Play with your critter
              """

        choice = raw_input ("Enter a number: ")

        #exit
        if choice == "0":
            print "GTFO."
        #listen to the critter
        elif choice == "1":
            crit.talk()
        #feed the crit crit critter
        elif choice == "2":
            crit.eat()
        #play with the crit crit critter
        elif choice == "3":
            crit.play()
        #some unknown choice
        else:
            print "\nwat"

    main ()
    raw_input ("\n\nHit enter to GTFO")
```

Comment: 1. Your indentation is broken.  2. At least one line at the beginning of the code is missing (something like `class Critter:`).

Comment: I've corrected your formatting, but is there still an indentation issue? What level is the code from `choice = None` and including the `while` loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In _getMood, there should be elifs.

```
    if unhappiness < 5:
        mood = "happy"
    elif 5 <= unhappiness <= 10:
        mood = "okay"
    elif 11 <= unhappiness <= 15:
        mood = "frustrated"
    else:
        mood = "mad"
```

Without them, it was actually only checking if unhappiness was between 11 and 15, and if not, setting the mood to mad. So unhappines from 0 to 10, and up from 16 meaned a critter was mad.

Answer (score 2):

I would say in cases like this, subsitute for a variable and trace the code.

unhappiness = 3

```
if unhappiness < 5:
    mood = "happy"
```

ok we became happy

```
if 5 <= unhappiness <= 10:
    mood = "okay"
```

nothing happened as 3 is not in range for 5 <= x <= 10

```
if 11 <= unhappiness <= 15:
    mood = "frustrated"
```

nothing happened as 3 is not in range for 11 < x < 15

```
else:
    mood = "mad"
```

else what? ah this refers to the last condition. so if it's not 11 < x < 15 then we're mad.

Subtitution of a variable with a value, and then tracing the code, line by line, is generally what you should try in situations like this, at least until it becomes second nature.